# Rails 4: Receiving the following error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby, forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am receiving the following error on a project of mine: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. I am trying to create an edit page for my code. Fairly new with Rails and trying to learn without scaffolding.

Controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
def new
  @book = Book.new 
  @authors = Author.all
end

def edit 
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])  
end 

def show
 #Notice how the @books is plural here. 
 @books = Book.all
 @authors = Author.all
 #@books = Book.where(id: params[:id])
end 

#Create method will save new entries 
def create 
 @book = Book.new(book_params)
 @authors = Author.all

 if @book.save
    flash[:success] = "Book Added to Databse!"
    redirect_to @book  
  else
    render 'new'
  end 
 end 

 private 

 #Note that this method will go up into the create method above. 

 def book_params 
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pub_date, :publisher, :author_id)
 end 
end
```

Model Page: (For Book)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :pub_date, :publisher, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true 
  belongs_to :author 
end
```

Model Page: (For Author)

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true 
  has_many :books 
end
```

Edit page:

```
<h1>Update a book entry</h2>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

   <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %> **ERROR SEEMS TO BE RIGHT HERE!!!**
     <%= render 'form' %>

     <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :pub_date %>
      <%= f.text_field :pub_date, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :publisher %>
    <%= f.text_field :publisher, class: 'form-control' %><br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select(:author_id, 
    @authors.collect {|a| [ a.name, a.id ]},              
    {:include_blank => 'Please select an author'}, 
    class: "form-control") %><br />
  </div>

   <%= f.submit 'Save Changes', class: "btn btn-primary" %> 

  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Render form page (_form.html.erb)

```
  <% if @book.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error") %> 
   prohibited this entry       from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
   <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>


  </div>
 <% end %>
```

SHOW PAGE:

```
    <div class="move">
   <h1>Showing Book Titles:</h1>
  </div><br />

 <div class="row">
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2><%= book.title %></h2> 
            <h2><%= book.publisher %></h2>
            <h2><%= book.pub_date %></h2>
            <h2><%= book.author.name %></h2>
            <h2><%= link_to "Edit", edit_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Log telling me what is wrong:

```
Started GET "/edit" for ::1 at 2015-08-14 16:49:17 -0400
Processing by BooksController#edit as HTML
  Rendered books/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (2.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
    3: <div class="row">
    4:   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    5: 
    6:     <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    7:       <%= render 'form' %>
    8: 
    9:       <div class="form-group">
  app/views/books/edit.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_books_edit_html_erb___525891009649529081_70260522100960'
```

I will say that I have deleted the first 14 books from my data base and so the first book start on ID 14. Not sure if that matters.

Finally, I have tried adding all of these different instance variables to my controller in the edit method:

```
   #@book = Book.where(id: params[:id])
   #@book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
   #@book = Book.all 
   #@book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
   #book = Book.new(book_params)

   #When I use the two below lines, 
  there are no error pages but create a new   entry. 
  #@book = Book.new 
  #@authors = Author.all
```

Any Help will be appreciated! Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: The book you are looking to edit is probably not in your database.  What is the book ID from your URL?  Are you certain that book exists in your database?  You can confirm through the Rails console.

Comment: I did have books in my database, before I added the edit feature. Once I added the edit feature, I deleted the books and then added one. (Which would be a book with ID 14. It is the only one in the database. I can click on its edit button on my show page and that is when I get the red page of death!

Comment: Even if I add a new book, which I just did, I get the following error message: Couldn't find Book with 'id'=id when I click on its edit button. Getting frustrating but part of the pain of learning!

Comment: If you use `rake routes` to look at your routes, you should have one like `edit/:id`.  So if book with id 14 exists in your database, you should be able to navigate to `www.example.com/edit/14`.  Separately, did you post your show view which contains the buttons to edit books?  If not, please post as the issue may be there.

Comment: I have added the show page above. When I head to http://localhost:3000/edit/14 I get a message that says no route matches. Could this line be wrong in my show page: <%= link_to "Edit", edit_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

Comment: Sorry the edit route should be `localhost:3000/books/14/edit` if you created it with something like `resources :books` (documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)).  If this doesn't work, either your routes are not defined correctly or book with ID 14 does not exist in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the first argument to `form_for` is a `nil` value (in this case `@book`).  Most of the times I've seen this, it's due to malformed controller actions, but that doesn't look to be the case here.  From what I can tell, it's one of two things:

1. You're trying to edit a Book that doesn't exist.  Do a `.nil?` check on it before deciding to render the form, and render an error message (or redirect) instead.
2. Your routes are broken, and the `edit` action is not rendering the `edit` view.  This is most likely *not* the case.

EDIT:

After updating with your template for `show`, this looks like your problem:

`<%= link_to "Edit", edit_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

I see two problems with this (though I'll need to see the output of `rake routes` to verify).  Firstly, you need to pass an argument to the edit path (without them, where would your params come from?).  Secondly, the default route for this would be `edit_book_path`.

Try this:

`<%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book), class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

Comment: Not sure if this is right but did: <%= form_for(@book).nil? do |f| %> and still get same error. I agree that I do not think option 2 is the problem. I think you are on to something in one. I know that the book is in the database but it is just not pulling it up. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Check to see if `@book` is `nil` before calling `form_for` - don't even call `form_for` if it is.  Instead, display an error of some kind.  I would generally check if it's nil inside the controller, and redirect to a different page entirely.

Comment: Still get the error message Couldn't find Book with 'id'=id with @book.nil?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming book ID 14 is in your database, you should be able to navigate to `localhost:3000/books/14/edit` if you created it with something like `resources :books` (documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)). If this doesn't work, either your routes are not defined correctly or book with ID 14 does not exist in your database.

On your show view, change the `link_to` line to:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

So two changes:

1. Again, assuming book is a Restful resource, when you run `rake_routes`, you should see the path to edit is `edit_book_path`.
2. You need to pass the `book` instance with the path so Rails knows which object you wish to edit.

I found the correct syntax [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Hope this helps.